# tinyMCE not rendering to popup

Tags: jquery, html, popup, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am using tinyMCE editor inside a POPUP window the popup was build by ajaxcall. The editor rendered correctly only first time when the popup is called by ajaxcall. After closing the popup and again when I open the popup the editor is not rendering it just shows the textarea with HTML code? Is there any way solve this issue.

tinyMCE 4.1.3

No Errors are showing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that the issue was caused by existing instance still being active, so I used the following code before initiating the tinyMCE:

```
// Remove existing instances of tinyMCE.
tinyMCE.remove();
```

Then:

```
tinyMCE.init()
```

Issue fixed.